# SQL - Display Minimum Value

Tags: sql, oracle, minimum

I am new to SQL Oracle and have been working on this for nearly 10 hrs.  I am trying to show record that has minimum share amount. Here is my code:

```
SELECT b.first_name||' '||b.last_name AS broker,
       MIN(t.share_amount)
FROM brokers b RIGHT OUTER JOIN
     trades t
     ON b.broker_id = t.broker_id
GROUP BY b.first_name||' '||b.last_name;
```

All this provides is a list of brokers and their share amounts. I just want the minimum.

Please help! I know it will be something simple but I cant figure out what.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `SELECT MIN(share_amount) FROM trades` then..

Comment: Minimum per broker or minimum for all brokers?

Comment: Needs to show 1 broker that has the least.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way that will return all rows that have the minimum share amount:

```
SELECT b.first_name||' '||b.last_name AS broker,
       t.share_amount
FROM   brokers b 
       right outer JOIN (SELECT *
                         FROM   (select broker_id,
                                        share_amount,
                                        min(share_amount) over () min_share_amount
                                 from   trades)
                         WHERE  share_amount = min_share_amount) t
         ON b.broker_id = t.broker_id;
```

This uses the MIN() analytic function to return the minimum share_amount across the whole trades table. Then we can filter the results to only bring back those rows whose share_amount matches the min_share_amount. Finally, we can join the brokers table to this subquery.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly.  Exactly what I needed. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be like

```
SELECT b.first_name||' '||b.last_name AS broker,
       MIN(t.share_amount)
FROM brokers b RIGHT OUTER JOIN
     trades t
     ON b.broker_id = t.broker_id
GROUP BY b.first_name||' '||b.last_name, t.share_amount;
```

Comment: This makes no sense

Comment: Thank you for the reply,

I am trying to get the broker who has made the least to be displayed only, not a list of each broker.